# Output HTML Form Element From Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select

I have just started out working with Javascript so this may sound like a rookie question.
I want to print out a select form element. But I am executing it in the javascript portion of my code as the list of options have to be accessed from an array in the script. I have used a div element in the HTML portion to output this select element. My code is as follows.

```
<head>
 <script>

    function currentWorlds()
    {
      var string="<select id='worldSelected'>";
      for(var i=0;i<universe.name.length;i++)
       {
          string+="<option value='"+i+"'>"+universe.name[i]+"</option>";
       }
      string+="</select>";

      $('#universeOptions').html(string);

    }

  $(function(){
     currentWorlds();
  });


 </script>
</head>

<body>
<form>          
Select from current games: <br>         
<div id="universeOptions"></div>
<input type="button" id="selectWorldButton" name="selectWorld" value="Select Game"> </br>

</form>
</body>
```

I have only included the relevant code with which I seem to be having a problem with. In this case universe is an object that has an array attribute called name. These names are the options that I want to display and based on the user's input, want to process. I cant seem to save the id of the select option, after I select it. Which means that when i console.log the value of worldSelected, it outputs a 0, once. And doesn't output anything after selecting a new option.  Is there something I am missing? Help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: can you please add the code where you're logging the selected world? and the 0 could be a result of you selecting the first element. the id of your first element is 0. cause i starts from 0 in the loop

Comment: it is in the main javascript function right after i call the currentWorlds() function.
'
console.log("World selected is ");
    console.log(document.getElementById("worldSelected").selectedIndex); '

Comment: check the answer I've just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would edit the code a bit... Try this and let me know if it works:

[Fiddle test here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Pwgj/2/)

View console logs on [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/fikusalu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
function currentWorlds(){
    var universe = {
        name: ["Uni A","Uni B","Uni C","Uni D","Uni E","Uni F","Uni G"]
    };
    var select = "<select id='worldSelected'></select>";
    $('#universeOptions').html(select);
    for(var i=0;i<universe.name.length;i++){
        $('#worldSelected').append($("<option></option>")
                           .attr("value",i)
                           .text(universe.name[i]));
    }
}

$(function(){
    currentWorlds();
    $('#worldSelected').change(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be logging out anything.

Comment: @Saima - Sorry updated the Jsbin link - http://jsbin.com/fikusalu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you for the help. Also as a clarification, the .append, .attr and .text methods that you used, are they used to manipulate ids? What do they exactly do?

Comment: @Saima: Good stuff. No they don't do anything with the id's themselves, .append() looks at the element specified, in this case by it's id, and then appends the option element to it, .attr() accesses the attribute 'value' of the option element that was just appended and gives it a value of 'i', and the same goes for .text() it accesses the text of the option element and adds the value of universe.name at the current position. Don't forget to accept! That is of course if you accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

code this using jquery to check for the selected value.

```
$('#worldSelected').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

this will log the value of the selectbox everytime a new value is selected. You can add this code above your currentWorlds function definition too. Note: This requires you to add the jquery library. As I've noted from the code you've posted, you have used jquery. So I assume you have linked it in your file.

Comment: I added in the code and it doesn't log anything out. It seems as though the worldSelected id is not being assigned any value to it based on the option i select.

Comment: You can right click on the select box and click on inspect element. In the developer tools, you can find the raw html code for your page. check if the options and select box have been assigned ids from there.

Comment: Just to clarify, by outputting the select element as a string using the div, will it function normally like an HTML form element? Or must i manipulate it some other way, such that it will accept the user's input?

Comment: It is a way to output html and does generally seem to work. But you can also add elements using the jquery library which has many ways to do so. .append() like https://api.jquery.com/append/ is a nice way to do so. But they all do the same things. Could you find the ids by using chrome developer tools?

Comment: Yes i managed to see the ids being allocated to the options and select box.  The id for worldSelected has no value attached to it. I was googling for an answer and i think that i have to attach an event handler to the select option when the user selects an option. But im not exactly sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this directly in your code:

```
function currentWorlds()
    {
      var string = document.createElement('select');
      string.setAttribute('id', 'worldSelected');
      var string1;

      for(var i=0;i<universe.name.length;i++)
       {
            string1 = document.createElement('option');
            string1.value = i;
            string1.text = universe.name[i];
            string.appendChild(string1);
       }

        document.getElementById('universeOptions').appendChild(string);

    }
```